# Magento - Show / hide CMS block when display mode 'Static Block and Products' selected in category

Tags: php, magento, catalog

On my top level categories, I'd like to use both static blocks and products along with layered navigation. The way I want to use it is that when none of the layered navigation options have been selected, a static block only displays (toys.phtml), whereas if any of the options are selected, the static block is hidden and only the products display (toys.phtml?brand=1).

Does anyone have any suggestions for this? I'm pretty sure I can hide the products (check URL string for $_GET variables), but not sure how I can hide the static block.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify or override the `Mage_Catalog_CategoryController (viewAction)` and add right before the `$this->renderLayout();` instruction, add the following:

```
if($this->getRequest()->getParam('brand'))
    $this->getLayout()->unsetBlock('yourstaticblockname');
```

Comment: Thanks for looking, it hasn't worked however. I've looked into it further and it appears when 'Mixed mode' is set for a category, it loads the block dynamically (CreateBlock('cms/block')) with a block id of $this->getCurrentCategory()->getLandingPage()

See catalog/block/category/view.php (getCmsBlockHtml()).

I've also noticed there are functions within that file such as isProductMode(), isContentMode(), isMixedMode(). Do you know of a way that the view mode could be set from the controller based on whether a param is set.

Comment: The cleanest way is adding an attribute to the class Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View ($_forced_display_mode) and set it from the controller $this->getLayout()->getBlock('products.listing')->setForcedDisplayMode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::DM_PAGE) (just an example). Then you have to modify the isMixedMode(), isProductMode() and isContentMode() to give priority to the $_forced_display_mode attribute over the database category attribute. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I've found another solution actually. In the same place you recommended to put your original code, I've put the following

if($category->getLevel()==2){
  $category->setDisplayMode('PAGE');
}

It seems to work perfectly, including when a parameter is selected in the layered navigation...

Comment: Mhm... yes, it could work that way, but you should be careful changing category attributes because that object could be saved by an event or some other component of Magento and the attribute will be persisted on the db. You need just to override it for a single category.